# Is possible split an image in two different layouts?

Tags: android, xml, image, layout

Is possible? I use some screen to help you understand.

This is my app without 2 layout:

[image]

End This is with second Layout (i need this second layout but 
I want to see the part of the image lost):[image]

This is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
tools:context=".Utenti.Profilo.ProfiloFragment">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_height="110dp">

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgProfilo"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="AndroHouse"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:id="@+id/nome_utente"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myImageView"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I dont see the coordinator layout in the xml code you shared

Comment: yes there is.. <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2">

Comment: Must have missed it sorry. Ok in a RelativeLayout, the z-value (height) of the items is directly related to the order you add them to the view. So just try swapping the places (in the layout file) of the coordinator layout and the linear layout.

Comment: so did it work? @francesco

Comment: yeah, work. sorry i cant give u point becouse im above 15 points

Comment: I added it as an actual answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In a RelativeLayout, the z-value (height) of the items is directly related to the order you add them to the view. And items are added to a view in a top-to-down order from an xml file

So just try swapping the places (in the layout file) of the coordinator layout and the linear layout.